# React : Neglecting Touch Events From the Child to a Parent

Tags: events, reactjs, react-native

I am stuck in a problem with React Native : 
I have my  simple View Hierarchy as :

```
<View><MapView/></View>
```

I want to listen to  the onClick listener of the Root View and do certain actions based on those listeners.At the meantime , I want my user to play with the Mapview, do certain Types of touch interactions without firing the listener intended for the parent ( which they unfortunately do :as a rule of thumb for parent -child thumbs )

```
<View><MapView pointerEvents="none"/><View>
```

This works somehow, but it won't provide me to interact with MapView at all . I am looking for a way in that We could interact with the MapView, at the meantime Touch events also not being fired to the parent View. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

**

**Capture ShouldSet Handlers**

**

**onStartShouldSetResponder** and onMoveShouldSetResponder are called with a bubbling pattern, **where the deepest node is called first**. That means that the deepest component will become responder **when multiple Views return true for *ShouldSetResponder handlers**. This is desirable in most cases, because it makes sure all controls and buttons are usable.

Assuming that you have a simple view hierarchy.

**sample-1**

In this case view2 is being controlled first, since it returns true it becomes clickable

```
<View onStartShouldSetResponder={(evt) => return true}> //View1
 <View onStartShouldSetResponder={(evt) =>//do something return true}>//View2
 </View>
</View>
```

**sample-2**

In this case view2 is being controlled first, since it returns false it is not clickable, then View1 is controlled since it returns true it becomes clickable.

```
<View onStartShouldSetResponder={(evt) => //do something return true}> //View1
 <View onStartShouldSetResponder={(evt) => return false}>//View2
 </View>
</View>
```

This hierarchy is useful when using with a component. For example you want to create a component called mapView and you want to make is clickable or not according to component you use it in.

```
class mapView extends Component
{
  .
  .
  render(){
return(
  <View onStartShouldSetResponder={(evt) => return {this.props.shouldBeClickable}>
   .
   .
  </View>
)
}
}


 -make your parent component clickable
class oneOfyourComponentUsingMapView extends Component
    {
      .
      .
      render(){
    return(
      <View onStartShouldSetResponder={(evt) =>//do something return true>
       <MapView shouldBeClickable={false}>
       .
       .
       </MapView>
      </View>
    )
    }
    }
```

-make your child component clickable

```
  class oneOfyourComponentUsingMapView2 extends Component
        {
          .
          .
          render(){
        return(
          <View>
           <MapView shouldBeClickable={true}>
           .
           .
           </View>
          </View>
        )
        }
        }
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html